# How to segue Interface Controllers programmatically without showing the back button?

Tags: ios, segue, apple-watch

Is there a way to programmatically change the view without showing the cancel or back button that shows up when using push or present?

i.e. these work, but show cancel or back

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"1home" context:nil];
[self presentControllerWithName:@"2home" context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setHidesBackButton on the navigationItem of your destinationViewController.

One good place of doing this is on the method prepareForSegue on your current viewController

Swift:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToHideBackButtonIdentifier" {
        segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToHideBackButtonIdentifier"]){
        [segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for the Apple Watch interface class